# How to remove sort phase in spark dataframe join?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join

I had created a bucketed table using below command in Spark:

```
df.write.bucketBy(200, "UserID").sortBy("UserID").saveAsTable("topn_bucket_test")
```

Size of Table : 50 GB

Then I joined another table (say t2 , size :70 GB)(Bucketed as before ) with above table on `UserId` column . I found that in the execution plan the table `topn_bucket_test` was being sorted (but not shuffled) before the join and I expected it to be neither shuffled nor sorted before join as it was bucketed. What can be the reason ? and how to remove sort phase for `topn_bucket_test`?

Comment: I think sort operations is default even though your tables are bucketBy byUserID. bucketBy only makes sure that your data is not shuffled again during join because key's are already co-located.

Comment: @kavetiraviteja Is there any way I can remove sort too .As the datasets are already sorted

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am concerned it is not possible to avoid the sort phase. When using the same `bucketBy` call it is unlikely that the physical bucketing will be identical in both tables. Imagine the first table having UserID ranging from 1 to 1000 and the second from 1 to 2000. Different UserIDs might end up in the 200 buckets and within those bucket there might be multiple different (and unsorted!) UserIDs.